# EM attenuation in free space at different frequencies

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Can anyone explain intuitively why electromagnetic radiation (according to the basic path loss equation in communications) experiences more attenuation at higher frequencies?

The equation states that the path loss $ L $ is proportional to $ d\times f $, where $ d $ is the distance the wave has propagated and $ f $ is the frequency of the wave.

Comment: Possibly related:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation

Comment: As a practical matter, note that for higher and higher frequencies, the unit gain antenna gets smaller, and will have a smaller and smaller capture area in a spherical isotropic model.

Comment: Sorry, I've not been on here for a while. I asked someone this question and they told me to look at the derivation of the Friss equation. After doing this this answer became obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observing the derivation of the equation of Friis "http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/friis.php", the answer to the question is because the effective aperture of an antenna is proportional to the square of the wavelength that the antenna operates at.